# Send email using PHP to only one recipient in mysql db

Tags: php

I have a table users, users have EmailAddress and I want to send an email to only one user, any user, I have a code for that but not working because user does not receive email,
any suggestions?

The code is:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>

<h2>send mail to only one user</h2>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="emailtosingur.php">
  To: <input type="text" name="to"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
  </form>
  <?php
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {
$email = $_POST['to'];
$query="SELECT * FROM users  WHERE EmailAddress ='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$check2 = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {



if ($check2)  {


// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

$to = "$email";
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$body = "E-mail body";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" ;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to,$subject, $message,$headers);

}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) Are you receiving specific errors in the console? 2) mysql_* is depreciated. Swap that code out for mysqli_*. 3) Do you have your mail configuration setup correctly and have you verified that just a simple call to mail() works? 4) Have you verified your database connection?

Comment: no ,i do not receiving any errors

Comment: and the rest of my question?

Comment: yes i have verifed my database connection

Comment: sorry ,no mysql_* is not depreciated

Comment: i have a code working to send mails to all users

Comment: but i need a code for only one user from database not all

Comment: are getting the value of $check2 ?

Comment: You'll need to persist your database connection using "global" too I do believe. I stay away from that nonsense so I can't remember if that's totally accurate. And yes, mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: not worked Fred ,i tried  $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress ='$email' LIMIT 1"; and $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress ='email@example.com'";

Comment: Should also point out that calling ini_set('display_errors',1); is pointless here. That needs to be one of the very first things you do in script execution, else it won't really do anything.

Comment: `email@example.com` was just an example. Replace it with an existing email. You can also try `$query="SELECT EmailAddress FROM users WHERE EmailAddress ='email@example.com'";` - Plus you'll need to change the `$email = $_POST['to'];` for it too.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted in an answer below. @user2326401 - which worked for me. See notes/comments inside. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:

Changed:

```
$to=$row['email'];
```

to:

```
$to=$row['EmailAddress'];
```

---

**Give this a try.** (Basic examples) and using `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` functions.

There are two methods below that both worked for me.

The first method uses `WHERE EmailAddress='".$to_recipient."'` where the email comes from a form input. Email must exist in database.

**Sidenote:** Change DB credentials `xxx` etc. with your own. And be careful to keep the `$dbc` variable the same in:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['to_recipient']); // important
```

### Method 1

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$hostname_gpd = "xxx";
$database_gpd = "xxx";
$password_gpd = "xxx";
$username_gpd = "xxx";

$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname_gpd, $username_gpd, $password_gpd, $database_gpd) or  trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {

$to_recipient = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['to_recipient']);
$email = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT `EmailAddress` FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='".$to_recipient."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($email) != 1)
    {
die("Sorry, that Email is not in our database.");
    }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($email))
    {
$to=$row['EmailAddress'];
    }

$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
// $body = "E-mail body";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" ;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: info@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
if(mail($to,$subject, $message,$headers))
    {
echo "Success! Email was sent to $to";
    }
 }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
To: <input type="text" name="to_recipient"><br>
Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

### Method 2

Simply change the following: (in code above)

**From:**

```
$to_recipient = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['to_recipient']);
```

**To:**

```
$to_recipient = "email_in_db@website.com"; // must exist in your DB
```

Comment: show me this error :Undefined index: email in /home1/myeasyw1/public_html/emailtosingur.php on line 26

Comment: Most probably because there is either no Email match, or you're not using my code exactly as shown. Did you modify it by any chance? Did you change the settings in it to "match" your own? I.e.: table name, column names, variables etc. @user2326401 - I tested this on "my" own server, so both of ours will "not" match. You need to make it work for yours.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's wrong. Change `$to=$row['email'];` to `$to=$row['EmailAddress'];` @user2326401 - I edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: i did not modify it ,i only put my own db ,my table name is the same users and the column names is also EmailAddress ,their is nothing to change ,where is my mistake?i tried 3 mails for 3 users in phpmyadmin but me showing also this error

Comment: What is the column name with the Email addresses in it? @user2326401 and did you make the changes I made above `$to=$row['email']; to $to=$row['EmailAddress'];`? and reloaded the page?

Comment: Oh, and in using the first example with the form, you did enter an (existing) Email address in the input field, right? @user2326401 and you did keep all `$dbc` variables for DB creds?

Comment: the column name in my phpmyadmin is EmailAddress also ,and i dill copy for all your code and paste in my php file ,only i changed db with my own db ,where is my mistake please ?

Comment: and you're not using any `mysql_` right for DB? My code all `mysqli_` notice the `i` in there? @user2326401 and not using `<?php include "base.php"; ?>` I hope?

Comment: i deleted my file emailtosingur.php ,and i did copy paste to your code ,and i only change xxx to my own db

Comment: I don't know then. This should have been a "Right out of the Box" piece of code. @user2326401 - to simply change DB creds, etc. What error are you getting now when you reloaded it?

Comment: the error is :Notice: Undefined index: email in /home1/myeasyw1/public_html/emailtosingur.php on line 26

Comment: well you didn't change the line from `$to=$row['email'];` to `$to=$row['EmailAddress'];` that's my guess. @user2326401 and when you do, upload and reload it/the page. Probably still in cache.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't opened db connection in this page. can you tell us how are you able to get the result of mysql_query ? if you don't get the result, you don't have no value for $check2, which means it wont even go inside the loop to email. Make sure you have configured your email server also

Comment: This needs to be a comment. It's not an answer.

Comment: i told the answer. You havent opened the connection in this page

Comment: i opened the connection <?php include "base.php"; ?>

Comment: my file connection is base.php and i used for another file to send mails to all users and it is working

Comment: what result are you getting when you echo $check2 ?

Comment: i had configured my email server also ,but the problem exit

Comment: Can you try putting this code after $result, $res1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r($res1['EmailAddress']); and tell what you are getting ?

Comment: i did ,i am getting nothing

Comment: exactly, which means nothing is coming out as result from that SQL query. So can you try running the same query using PHPMyAdmin. tell me, if its showing result there ??

Comment: when i use phpmyadmin the mail received of course ,then i thing the code is wrong ,can you tell me where is the mistake please ?

Comment: i am asking you to echo $query="SELECT * FROM users  WHERE EmailAddress ='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$res1=mysql_fetch_array($result); print_r($res1);  then use the same mysql code in PHPMyAdmin to see you are getting result there ? just copy paste those code after $email = $_POST['to'];

Comment: also i did ,nothing happen

Comment: do you have the email that you are entering in your DB ?

Comment: i have ,but i do not speak english well

Comment: I am asking, is there entered email as a value in the column EmailAddress in users table ?

Comment: it is ok ,i will add you

Comment: just one thing, try to open a connection like this $g_link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpass') just before the mysql_query and also make sure you replace the values with your ones from base.php. i still believe, its connection issue. i also believe, the mail will go if you remove that if ($check2)

Comment: i did echo in phpmy admin and now show me this error

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress ='$email'"' at line 1

Comment: Echo is php construct. I wanted you to echo the query in php page then run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: i opened a connection and i replaced the values from base,then i deleted if($check2) ,but the problem exit

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress ='$email'"' at line 1

Comment: i did that and i told you what error me showing just in my phpadmin

Comment: I will clear it and tell you whats wrong, please send me database also

Comment: i sent my file connection base.php

Comment: i will send you table just moment please